How to select bar range for indicator calculation in pinescript? Converting volume profile to interactive custom range volume profile
I'm trying to rework the volume profile script to an interactive one where I can select a custom bar range for volume profile calculation similar to the paid version on tradingview. I already made the script calculate correctly based on bar_index inputs, but the script plots the VP rows wrong. For some reason, it takes the pivot point high or low that is within [lastbar] index range from "bbars" which should be the beginning of volume calculation (screenshot). Instead, the script should fit all the VP rows to the high/low range between "bbars" and "lastbar" bar_index values, making the profile more detailed. The issue comes from this line: top = ta.highest(bbars)[lastbar] bot = ta.lowest(bbars)[lastbar] which I don't know how to code in other way.
Also if you know how to convert the bar_index inputs (start bar/end bar) into interactive time.input it would be very helpful, thanks for your help and time!
Current script:
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © LonesomeTheBlue

//@version=5
indicator('Volume Profile / Custom Range', overlay=true, max_boxes_count=200, max_bars_back=501)
bbars = input.int(title='Start Bar', defval=100, minval=1, maxval=500)+1
lastbar = input.int(title='End Bar', defval=40, minval=1, maxval=500)
cnum = input.int(title='Row Size', defval=100, minval=5, maxval=100)
percent = input.float(70., title='Value Area Volume %', minval=0, maxval=100)
poc_color = input.color(defval=#ff0000, title='POC Color', inline='poc')
poc_width = input.int(defval=2, title='Width', minval=1, maxval=5, inline='poc')
vup_color = input(defval=color.new(color.blue, 30), title='Value Area Up')
vdown_color = input(defval=color.new(color.orange, 30), title='Value Area Down')
up_color = input(defval=color.new(color.blue, 75), title='UP Volume')
down_color = input(defval=color.new(color.orange, 75), title='Down Volume')
show_poc = input.bool(defval = true, title = "Show POC Label")

top = ta.highest(bbars)[lastbar]
bot = ta.lowest(bbars)[lastbar]
dist = (top - bot) / 800
step = (top - bot) / cnum

// calculate/keep channel levels
levels = array.new_float(cnum + 1)
for x = 0 to cnum by 1
    array.set(levels, x, bot + step * x)

// get the volume if there is intersection
get_vol(y11, y12, y21, y22, height, vol) =>
    nz(math.max(math.min(math.max(y11, y12), math.max(y21, y22)) - math.max(math.min(y11, y12), math.min(y21, y22)), 0) * vol / height)

if barstate.islast
    // calculate/get volume for each channel and candle
    volumes = array.new_float(cnum * 2, 0.)
    for bars = lastbar to bbars - 1 by 1
        body_top = math.max(close[bars], open[bars])
        body_bot = math.min(close[bars], open[bars])
        itsgreen = close[bars] >= open[bars]

        topwick = high[bars] - body_top
        bottomwick = body_bot - low[bars]
        body = body_top - body_bot

        bodyvol = body * volume[bars] / (2 * topwick + 2 * bottomwick + body)
        topwickvol = 2 * topwick * volume[bars] / (2 * topwick + 2 * bottomwick + body)
        bottomwickvol = 2 * bottomwick * volume[bars] / (2 * topwick + 2 * bottomwick + body)
        for x = 0 to cnum - 1 by 1
            array.set(volumes, x, array.get(volumes, x) + (itsgreen ? get_vol(array.get(levels, x), array.get(levels, x + 1), body_bot, body_top, body, bodyvol) : 0) + get_vol(array.get(levels, x), array.get(levels, x + 1), body_top, high[bars], topwick, topwickvol) / 2 + get_vol(array.get(levels, x), array.get(levels, x + 1), body_bot, low[bars], bottomwick, bottomwickvol) / 2)
            array.set(volumes, x + cnum, array.get(volumes, x + cnum) + (itsgreen ? 0 : get_vol(array.get(levels, x), array.get(levels, x + 1), body_bot, body_top, body, bodyvol)) + get_vol(array.get(levels, x), array.get(levels, x + 1), body_top, high[bars], topwick, topwickvol) / 2 + get_vol(array.get(levels, x), array.get(levels, x + 1), body_bot, low[bars], bottomwick, bottomwickvol) / 2)

    totalvols = array.new_float(cnum, 0.)
    for x = 0 to cnum - 1 by 1
        array.set(totalvols, x, array.get(volumes, x) + array.get(volumes, x + cnum))

    int poc = array.indexof(totalvols, array.max(totalvols))

    // calculate value area
    totalmax = array.sum(totalvols) * percent / 100.
    va_total = array.get(totalvols, poc)
    int up = poc
    int down = poc
    for x = 0 to cnum - 1 by 1
        if va_total >= totalmax
            break
        uppervol = up < cnum - 1 ? array.get(totalvols, up + 1) : 0.
        lowervol = down > 0 ? array.get(totalvols, down - 1) : 0.
        if uppervol == 0 and lowervol == 0
            break
        if uppervol >= lowervol
            va_total += uppervol
            up += 1
            up
        else
            va_total += lowervol
            down -= 1
            down

    maxvol = array.max(totalvols)
    for x = 0 to cnum * 2 - 1 by 1
        array.set(volumes, x, array.get(volumes, x) * bbars / (3 * maxvol))


    // Draw VP rows
    var vol_bars = array.new_box(cnum * 2, na)
    for x = 0 to cnum - 1 by 1
        box.delete(array.get(vol_bars, x))
        box.delete(array.get(vol_bars, x + cnum))
        array.set(vol_bars, x, box.new(bar_index - bbars + 1, 
                                       array.get(levels, x + 1) - dist, 
                                       bar_index - bbars + 1 + math.round(array.get(volumes, x)), 
                                       array.get(levels, x) + dist, 
                                       border_width=0, 
                                       bgcolor=x >= down and x <= up ? vup_color : up_color))
        array.set(vol_bars, x + cnum, box.new(bar_index - bbars + 1 + math.round(array.get(volumes, x)), 
                                              array.get(levels, x + 1) - dist, 
                                              bar_index - bbars + 1 + math.round(array.get(volumes, x)) + math.round(array.get(volumes, x + cnum)), 
                                              array.get(levels, x) + dist, 
                                              border_width=0, 
                                              bgcolor=x >= down and x <= up ? vdown_color : down_color))

    // Draw POC line and label
    poc_level = (array.get(levels, poc) + array.get(levels, poc + 1)) / 2
    var line poc_line = na
    line.delete(poc_line)
    poc_line := line.new(bar_index - bbars + 1, poc_level, bar_index - bbars + 2, poc_level, extend=extend.right, color=poc_color, width=poc_width)
    
    if show_poc
        var label poc_label = na
        label.delete(poc_label)
        poc_label := label.new(bar_index + 15, poc_level, 
                               text = "POC: " + str.tostring(math.round_to_mintick(poc_level)),
                               style = close >= poc_level ? label.style_label_up : label.style_label_down)


I'm trying to rework the volume profile script to an interactive one where I can select a custom bar range for volume profile calculation similar to the paid version on tradingview. I already made the script calculate correctly based on bar_index inputs, but the script plots the VP rows wrong. For some reason, it takes the pivot point high or low that is within [lastbar] index range from "bbars" which should be the beginning of volume calculation (attached screenshot). Instead, the script should fit all the VP rows to the high/low range between "bbars" and "lastbar" bar_index values, making the profile more detailed. The issue comes from this line: top = ta.highest(bbars)[lastbar] bot = ta.lowest(bbars)[lastbar] which I don't know how to code in other way.
